# C code to find mean,mode, and median of two user input arrays

Tags: c, arrays, mean, median, mode

I'm about 100 lines in and the code works but the values are incorrect, any ideas how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 6
#define size2 6
float mean(int arr1[],int arr2[],int i,float *mn1,float *mn2){
  int sum1=0,sum2=0;
  for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
      sum1=sum1+arr1[i];
      sum2=sum2+arr2[i];
  }
  *mn1=sum1/6;
  *mn2=sum2/6;
}
int median(int arr1[],int arr2[],int n,int n2,float *median1,float *median2){

  if(n%2==0){
      *median1=(arr1[(n-1)/2]+arr1[n/2])/2.0;
  }
  else{
      *median1=arr1[n/2];
  }
      if(n2%2==0){
      *median2=(arr2[(n2-1)/2]+arr2[n2/2])/2.0;
  }
  else{
      *median2=arr2[n2/2];
  }
  return *median2;
  return *median1;
}
int mode(int arr1[],int arr2[],int i,int q,int *max,int *max2){
  int xs[1000]={0};
  int xs2[1000]={0};
  for(i=0;i<6;i++){
      xs[arr1[i]]++;
      if(xs[arr1[i]]>*max){
          *max=xs[arr1[i]];
      }
  }
  for(q=0;q<6;q++){
      xs2[arr2[q]]++;
      if(xs2[arr2[q]]>*max2){
          *max2=xs2[arr2[i]];
      }
  }
  return *max;
  return *max2;
}
int main()
{
  float mn1=0.0,mn2=0.0;
  int arr1[size],arr2[size2];
  int i=0,q=0,temp,n=6,n2=6;
  float median1=0.0;
  float median2=0.0;
  int max=0,max2=0;
  printf("please fill array 1: ");
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
      scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
  }
      printf("please fill array 2: ");
  for(i=0;i<size2;i++){
      scanf("%d",&arr2[i]);
  }
   for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
      for(q=0 ; q<size-1 ; q++){
          if(arr1[q]>arr1[q+1]){
              temp=arr1[q];
              arr1[q]=arr1[q+1];
              arr1[q+1]=temp;}}}
   for(i=0 ; i<size2 ; i++){
      for(q=0 ; q<size2-1 ; q++){
          if(arr2[q]>arr2[q+1]){
              temp=arr2[q];
              arr2[q]=arr2[q+1];
              arr2[q+1]=temp;}}}
              if(mn1&&median1&&max>mn2&&median2&&max2){
                  printf("You're playing more video games you have to spent more time studying.\n ");
              }
             else{
                  printf("Good, you're spending considerable time in studying.\n");
              }
  mn1=mean( arr1, arr2, i, &mn1, &mn2);
  mn2=mean( arr1, arr2, i, &mn1, &mn2);
  median1=median( arr1, arr2, n, n2, &median1, &median2);
  median2=median( arr1, arr2, n, n2, &median1, &median2);
  max=mode( arr1, arr2, i, q, &max, &max2);
  max2=mode( arr1, arr2, i, q, &max, &max2);
  printf("\nMean of arr1 is: %0.1f\t Median of arr1 is:%0.1f\t Mode of arr1 is: %d\n",mn1,median1,max);
  printf("\nMean of arr2 is: %0.1f\t Median of arr2 is:%0.1f\t Mode of arr2 is: %d\n",mn2,median2,max2);
  return 0;
  return 0;
}
```

if I input the numbers 4 5 5 2 8 9 for arr1 and the numbers  2 3 1 4 8 4 for arr2 I get this

Mean of arr1 is: 5.0     Median of arr1 is:5.0   Mode of arr1 is: 2

Mean of arr2 is: 1.$     Median of arr2 is:3.0   Mode of arr2 is: 2

Comment: `sum1/6`. That does integer division. Try `sum1/6.0`.

Comment: You need to open up your C textbook again and start reading.  Take a look at how functions and return values work for starters.

Comment: Note that `i` is misused in: `float mean(int arr1[],int arr2[],int i,float *mn1,float *mn2){
  int sum1=0,sum2=0;
  for(i=0;i<=5;i++){` — you pass `i` as an argument, and then set it to 0.  It might be best to rename the argument as `n` and then create a local variable `i` and run the loop `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`.  The `<=` in the original condition is dubious too.

Comment: It would help if you used an orthodox [C indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) — I recommend Allman (my preference) or a 1TBS variant.  Using Pico style may be appropriate for Pico, but C is not Pico.   If you have any choice in the matter, do not use Pico style for C.  The `if` statement is woefully misindented if I'm reading the code correctly.

Comment: The two blocks of code sorting the arrays should be one function called twice.  You should check that the `scanf()` operations succeed.  You should consider a function to manage the reading of the arrays.  Neither of the calls `mn1=mean( arr1, arr2, i, &mn1, &mn2);
  mn2=mean( arr1, arr2, i, &mn1, &mn2);` makes much sense.  The function doesn't return a value (though its definition says it should — the compiler should be warning you about that).  And even if it did return a value, you saved two outputs in `mn1` and `mn2` passed by reference.  The double call is unnecessary and undesirable.